# How to register services in scoped lifestyle behaving like PerWebRequest using castle windsor?

Tags: c#, owin, castle-windsor, owin-middleware

I am working on self-hosted web api using **OWIN** and I need to register a service per scope lifestyle using Castle Windsor.

I know that using **HttpContext** I can achieve that using **PerWebRequest** or **HybridPerWebRequestPerThread** lifestyle but in my case I don't have HttpContext.

I have created the following owin middleware which will be the first and the last middleware will be executed during the request :

```
public class SetupMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{

    public SetupMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("next");
        }
    }


    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        IDisposable scope = null;
        try
        {
           //here I am starting new scope
            var container= IoCResolverFactory.GetContainer();
            scope = container.BeginScope();

            await Next.Invoke(context);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            //here I am disposing it
            scope?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And when I Startup my application I register my service inside the IoC container as following:

```
container.BeginScope();
container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().ImplementedBy<CurrentRequestService>().LifestyleScoped());
```

The problem when I resolve instance of CurrentRequestService, it does not work as per scope which owin middleware will begin it when a new request comes and dispose it when it finishes.

Could you please guide me to how can I register services per scope to behave like PerWebRequest in my application?

Comment: Everything looks correct except of `container.BeginScope()` before `container.Register` (I don't see any necessity here). Can you share your `Startup` class and code where you are resolving the service.

Comment: So how can I register that service using scoped lifestyle It will throw scope "Scope was not available. Did you forget to call container.BeginScope()?" exception

Comment: On startup I have some code which needs to resolve that service.
I am resolving using this code "container.Resolve<ICurrentRequestService>();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected that I should define a custom scope to be started and dispose within a middleware .

I have created the following custom scope accessor:

```
public class OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor : IScopeAccessor
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

    ILifetimeScope IScopeAccessor.GetScope(CreationContext context)
    {
        IOwinContext owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        string key = SetupMiddleware.EnvironmentKey;
        return owinContext.Environment[key] as ILifetimeScope;
    }
}
```

Then I have modified my SetupMiddleware as followings:

```
public class SetupMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public const string EnvironmentKey = "WindsorOwinScope";

    public SetupMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("next");
        }
    }


    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope = new DefaultLifetimeScope();

        try
        {
            context.Environment[EnvironmentKey] = lifetimeScope;

            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Environment.Remove(EnvironmentKey);
            lifetimeScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I registered my service using the above scope :

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().ImplementedBy<CurrentRequestService>().LifestyleScoped<OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor>());
```

**PS:**

SetupMiddleware should be the first middleware in the owin pipeline.

I hope my code will help others.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many scopes.

To use the scope that is controlled by `SetupMiddleware` you need to resolve `ICurrentRequestService` service somewhere deeper than `SetupMiddleware` during request processing (e.g. in controller action).

Thus, `SetupMiddleware` will create the scope, then in controller action `ICurrentRequestService` will be resolved inside that scope, finally `SetupMiddleware` will dispose `ICurrentRequestService` by calling `scope.Dispose()`.

As I understand, currently you have something like this:

```
// when application starts. Executes once
container.BeginScope(); // the 1st (application) scope beginning. 
container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().ImplementedBy<CurrentRequestService>().LifestyleScoped());
var service = IoCResolverFactory.GetContainer().Resolve<ICurrentRequestService>();

//in SetupMiddleware. This code executes on every web request
    var container = IoCResolverFactory.GetContainer(); 
    scope = container.BeginScope(); // the request scope beginning

    // here others middlewares 
    // here you can resolve ICurrentRequestService to use the request scope

    scope?.Dispose(); // the request scope end
```

Thus, `service` uses the application scope instead of the request scope.

Comment: When I register my service as following " container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().Instance(currentRequestService).LifestyleScoped());" it does not dispose it, and when I register it as "container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().ImplementedBy<CurrentRequestService>().LifestyleScoped()" it does not resolve it inside my controller

Comment: I've created a sample [project](https://github.com/Albertronic/OwinSelfHostWithCastleWindsor). There you will find service resolvings in both scopes

Comment: I don't think it's gonna work I still get instance of CurrentRequestService with their properties as null(they have been disposed inside the controller) . I think I should create custom scope